# Correct way to check if yajra/laravel table was already initialized?

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, yajra-datatable

In use laravel 5.7 / jquery 3 / blade app I use yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle 8 
and open it in modal dialog and I open this dialog for the 2nd/3rd time
I got warning message :

```
DataTables warning: table id=get-fee-dt-listing-table - Cannot reinitialise DataTable
```

In blade file :

```
<div class="modal-body">

    <div class="table-responsive dataTables_header">
        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped text-primary" id="get-fee-dt-listing-table">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
```

and in .js file:

```
bookingsAndAvailability.prototype.showFeesSelection = function () {
    console.log('showFeesSelection::')
    $("#div_check_in_fees_modal").modal({
        "backdrop": "static",
        "keyboard": true,
        "show": true
    });



    // var dtListingTable= document.getElementById('get-fee-dt-listing-table')
    // dtListingTable  = null // If to uncomment these 2 lines - they do not help

    $("#get-fee-dt-listing-table").html('') // // If to uncomment these 2 lines - they do not help

    oTable = $('#get-fee-dt-listing-table').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        language: {
            "processing": "Loading fees..."
        },
```

I close the modal with command :

```
$("#div_check_in_fees_modal").modal('hide');
```

which is correct way to check if table was already initialised?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$.fn.dataTable.isDataTable()` for this.

From the docs:

> This method provides the ability to check if a table node is already a
>   DataTable or not. This can be useful to ensure that you don't
>   re-initialise a table that is already a DataTable.
>
> Please note that this is a static function and is accessed through the
>   $.fn.dataTable object, not an API instance. It can be accessed at any
>   time, even before any DataTables have been created on the page.

```
if ( ! $.fn.DataTable.isDataTable( '#example' ) ) {
  $('#example').dataTable();
}
```

In your case it would be something like this:

```
if (! $.fn.DataTable.isDataTable('#get-fee-dt-listing-table')) {
    oTable = $('#get-fee-dt-listing-table').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        language: {
            "processing": "Loading fees..."
        },
    ...
}
```